# AES Decryption in SWIFT4 Producing null Value

Tags: macos, encryption, swift4

I'm using an extension method to decrypt a string which is encrypted by the server side php script using AES Algorithm.

The following is the extension method used

```
func aesDecrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = NSData(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

            let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algoritm,
                                      options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      iv,
                                      data.bytes, data.length,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)

            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
                return unencryptedMessage
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

This sometimes returns a null value

```
unencode = responseString?.aesDecrypt(key: "mykey", iv: "value");
```

I cannot figure out the exact reason why this happens.The responseString was not null when this happened.

Please advice

Comment: Are you always using the same key (if so what is the length) and same iv?

Comment: What were the values of cryptStatus when it happened?

Comment: I have replaced this code with cryptoswift,thanks for all your help.

Comment: still are you looking for solution for this problem ???