# CryptoSWIFT- Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, cryptoswift

Im using `cryptoswift` to decrypt a string

```
let decrypted2 =  try AES(key: "35%6HyBW", iv: "erewf^%", blockMode: .CBC, padding: .pkcs7).decrypt(text2)
```

But I keep getting `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` Complie time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two typos here.

#1, the prototype you're using doesn't exist.  Blockmode takes a `CBC(iv:)` argument.

#2, you need to convert strings into a [`[UInt8]` array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255402/swift-how-to-convert-a-string-to-uint8-array).

So use:

```
let aes = try AES(key: [UInt8]("35%6HyBW".utf8), blockMode: CBC(iv: [UInt8]("erewf^%".utf8)), padding: .pkcs7)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Im just learning swift.decrypted2 is an AES object.How can I get the decrypted string from it.

Comment: I just modified my answer a little bit.  You're creating an AES object (for encrypting and decrypting).  So what's missing is that you need to have your encrypted data/string and pass ***that*** to the AES `.decrypt` function.  Take a look at the CryptoSwift project's `.playground` and you'll see a nice, self explanatory example under the "ChaChat20" header.

Comment: Thanks for the update,I have managed to encrypt a string using the following code ' let aes1 =  try AES(key: "passwordpassword", iv: "drowssapdrowssap") 
                let sdata =  try aes1.encrypt(Array(akey.utf8)) ' But the issue is that I cannot use the Mac System Serial Number as the key, it seems that AES requires a specific key length ,I cannot change encryption key as the old implementations uses this method.Im trying to change this because I get `null` value for decrypted string in some cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611187/aes-decryption-in-swift4-producing-null-value

Comment: How can I replicate the same thing with cryptoswift.Please advice

Comment: Ask a separate question (since it's a separate question) and I'll try to respond to that one, too.

Comment: I have opened a new question.Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727447/migrating-common-crypto-aesencryption-to-cryptoswift-as-decrypted-string-turns-n