# Migrating Common Crypto AESEncryption to CryptoSWIFT as decrypted string turns null in some cases

Tags: swift, macos, encryption, swift4, cryptoswift

Im using the following code to encrypt and decrypt a string using AES Encryption.I'm using common crypto by adding a Bridging Header.

```
extension String {

    func aesEncrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.count)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {


            let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)



            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algoritm,
                                      options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      iv,
                                      (data as NSData).bytes, data.count,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)

            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
                return base64cryptString


            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func aesDecrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = NSData(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

            let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algoritm,
                                      options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      iv,
                                      data.bytes, data.length,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)

            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
                return unencryptedMessage
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }


}
```

In some cases the decrypted string returns null, this leads to program crash.Im currently trying to replace this with CryptoSwift,but I cannot figure out how to set the Encryption Scheme to match these settings.Please advice.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you're using the Macintosh serial number to be the key.  Could you limit the serial number to 16 bytes, as Marcin (the author of cryptoswift) suggests?  Also, using a serial number is ***INCREDIBLY RISKY*** and I wouldn't do it, as Macintosh serial numbers can change (e.g. when I send in my laptop into AppleCare or repair center, they frequently swap out the motherboards and that can change the serial number).

Answer (score 1):

Check the README https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#aes here you'll find the AES examples that should be straightforward to use for your needs. Eg. To encrypt data, you do this:

```
do {
    let aes = try AES(key: "keykeykeykeykeyk", iv: "drowssapdrowssap") // aes128
    let ciphertext = try aes.encrypt(data.bytes)
} catch { }
```

Comment: My key length  does not work with the sample code provided.

Comment: why? your key should be 16 bytes long (for AES128)

Comment: I got some invalid key size error when testing out.

Comment: Maybe key size is invalid then. What is the key size?

Comment: I cannot change the key to preserve reverse compatibility.

Comment: don't change it. You never used more than kCCKeySizeAES128 bytes of your key anyway.